# keep object position when resizing stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, resize

im trying to keep a object in a certain position in the screen, without resizing it too (with the stage)

```
function Resize(e:Event = null):void
{
    if ((stage.stageWidth)/(stage.stageHeight) > fundos.width/fundos.height)
    {
        fundos.width = stage.stageWidth;
        fundos.scaleY = fundos.scaleX;
    }
    else
    {
        fundos.height = stage.stageHeight;
        fundos.scaleX = fundos.scaleY;
    }
    fundos.x = (stage.stageWidth - fundos.width) /2;
    fundos.y = (stage.stageHeight - fundos.height) /2;  

    setas.x = (stage.stageWidth - setas.width + 505) /2;
    setas.y = (stage.stageHeight - setas.height);   
}
```

my stage is resizing all ok (keeping the aspect ratio) and im trying to add a nav img that would stay in the same position as i resize the browser screen

how can i do that?

Comment: You want to keep the object in the same place with respect to what? If you have an absolute layout and you specify x and y coordinates for your component, as well as width and height properties, it will stay there and be that size through any amount of resizing. I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the stage event Event.RESIZE with

```
stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
```

It's dispatched when the user resize the stage, by any way (zooming in the browser, resizing in

In the event handler, run the code snippet you gave to us.

---

Also, don't forget to use

```
stage.scaleMode = flash.display.StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Or the content will be resized.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example. Blob sprite is the Object which keep the initial position (50, 50)

```
package {
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;

[SWF(backgroundColor="#00FF00", frameRate="31")]
public class Application extends Sprite {

    private var blob:Sprite;


    public function Application() {
        if(stage) {
            init();
        } else {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
    }

    private function init() : void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize);

        blob = new Sprite();
        blob.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        blob.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 100);
        blob.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(blob);
    }

    private function resize(event : Event) : void {
        // Do nothing on blob's Object
    }

}
```

}

The stage is well resized (ratio) but blob keep the position even if you set (in your embed) swf width and height to 100%